# How to resolve add new item and delete old item in Django?

Tags: python, django

I demo a order sale page. When I edit the order I want to update the items of order in some case: Example: I have a list of item of order in database like this:

`=============
Item Quantity
1     10
2     15
3     30
=============`

Case 1: When edit order if I add new a item 4 with quantity 20 how can I add only new item but still keep old item to database like this:

`=============
Item Quantity
1     10
2     15
3     30
4     20
=============`

Case 2: If I delete item how can I delete only item 2 but still keep old item to database like this:
`=============
Item Quantity
1     10
3     30
4     20
=============`

Case 3: If I delete item 2, item 3 and add new item 5 how can I delete item 2, item 3 and add new item 5 like this:

`=============
Item Quantity
1     10
4     20
5     5
=============`

I'm stuck. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the 'Item' column the ID of the Item? Or some other field property?

Comment: Yes that is ID of Item

Comment: So for me, Django automatically orders rows by ID, so the behavior that you're describing already works. I'm not sure what your database is doing, can you describe what happens?

Answer (score 2):

Add a class Meta to your model class, and an "ordering" tuple to specify the field to be ordered by.
Example:

```
class MyItem(models.Model):
    item = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    quantity = models.IntField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('item',)
```

This will order call MyItem by field "item"
Another option is to use order_by function on the query set:

```
MyItem.objects.all().order_by('item')
```